# How to save a finetuned model on AzureML?

Tags: azure, huggingface-transformers, azure-machine-learning-service, fine-tuning

I'm running a HuggingFace fine-tuning in a notebook in AzureML.  When I run the following locally, I get various files (model bin file, a bunch of jsons) saved in the appropriate directory.

```
trainer.train()
trainer.save_model()
```

However, when I do the same on the AzureML vm, although I see the directory in my compute folder structure, it's empty.  How would I save the model?

Comment: Could you please add details how exactly you do run on AML VM? Is that pipeline run on a cluster via workspace or you connect to a compute instance remote kernel? are you using VS code or Jupyter? What do you use to train, TensorFlow, PyTorch? What is the permissions for the saving folder?

Comment: I think you do need to [specify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/machine-learning/train-model/huggingface/fine-tune-model#train-and-log-to-mlflow) the directory where you are trying to save the model in `trainer.save_model()`.

Comment: It seems that there was a lag and that it did actually save.  I'll need to re-run this again just to see if I have the same issue.  Btw, I did specify the directory through the output_dir attribute of TrainingArguments.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ro.oT mentioned either you can use `trainer.save_model()` by specifying output directory
[Refer this](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.33.3/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Trainer.save_model)

[image]

or
you can use `trainer.push_to_hub()`
to share it in your hub.
[Refer this](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.33.3/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Trainer.push_to_hub)

Make sure to login to your hub using
below code before running above code.

```
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()
```